# What are the shortcut keys to change to the next and previous tab in Eclipse on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to switch from one file to another in the Eclipse editor (in the Java perspective) from the keyboard (and bind those key combinations to buttons on my mouse).  What are the shortcut keys for switching the current tab to the next or previous?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=267097&), switching editors are:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

, which you can remap to:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

---

Note, as mentioned in that same thread:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> lists all the opened editors, allowing to quickly select one
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> lists all the active key bindings.

---

The [bug 86248](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86248) helped introduced the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, which [Bjorn Tipling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66475/bjorn-tipling) [reports working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381202/6309) on Mac with a <kbd>Fn</kbd> in front of it.

Answer (score 83):

Mac OS X:

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Effectively <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd> as given in the first comment for @wibbe01's answer.

Answer (score 7):

If I were you I would just go to the eclipse menu, then preferences.  Under the general section of the tree there is a section called "Keys"  In there you will find things for "Next Editor" or whatever other keyboard shortcuts you are looking for.  Map them to what makes sense to you....then you're happy like this :) or maybe even like this :D.

Enjoy.

Comment: Actually, there is a keyboard shortcut to switch between tabs that is not listed on the preference pane you point out above. Namely, this shortcut is CTRL-pageup/down. This shortcut works out to be a lot faster than the one stated above as it does not prompt the developer with a popup box. I would love to define this keyboard shortcut to be equivalent to safari's tab switching shortcut, namely, CMD-{ and CMD-}. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @Raffi Khatchadourian: Well that is awesome and handy.  Except it is fn + ctrl + up/down on my macbook with lack of pg up/dwn keys...which makes it even worse.  CMD-{ and CMD-} would be awesome.  I looked through the eclipse documentation and didn't even see mention of it though, so I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to find a way.  I'm going to keep looking throughout the evening as that would be handy.  Although I would choose cmd+left/right so it was like adium :).

Comment: @Raffi Khatchadourian:  Nevermind, I lied.  I found it.  It is called "Next tab" and "Previous tab" in that bindings listing.  cmd+] and cmd+[ are already taken for forward and backward history of tabs selected though.  But nothing stopping you from overriding them like I just did!  Hope that helps.

Comment: @wibbe01 Aren't the safari shortcuts cmd+} and cmd+{?

Comment: @Raffi Khatchadourian: Yeah.  I guess I didn't see "shift" and didn't notice you had the squiggly brackets.  I wish everything was standardized for switching tabs :)....would make my mind have to think a whole lot less anyway.  Did changing those mappings work for you?

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse's preference panel, go to Keys. The command is called `Next Tab` and `Previous Tab`, just map these to whatever you want. In my case since I normally use mvim are:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: While this isn't *THE* answer, this is the *BEST* answer!  Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify: Eclipse->Preferences->General->Keys

Answer (score 3):

You can change all shortcut keys in preferences by pressing ctrl+shift+L 2 times . Switching tab in Eclipse (ctrl+F6) is not easy to press. So you can make it ctrl+tab or whatever you want.

Comment: what is the mac equivalent of this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have my F keys mapped to the default setting, I had to use fn-command-F8

I figured it out by first confirming command-F8 was indeed mapped under command-shift-L